# Is there something like RequestTheme in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

i'm developing some winRT apps and there i have the property

```
RequestTheme
```

which i can set to Light and Dark. So i can overwrite the user default theme if i want to display my app always e.g. in Dark.

Is there something equal in windows phone 7 programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [good article](http://www.kirupa.com/windowsphone/detecting_the_theme.htm) written by Kirupa Chinnathambi that covers the theme type acquisition. That is the best starting point here.